# Mutual SSL Authentication with gSOAP

Tags: c, ssl, gsoap, mutual-authentication

I am trying to connect with a SOAP Service which requires Mutual SSL Authentication.

We created a self-signed certificate and transferred it to the service operator for them to verify our connections. Likewise, they sent us a copy of their ssl certificate.

I have been able to successfully connect to an get the expected SOAP response from the service by using openssl s_client and manually entering the HTTP request, headers and SOAP content.
I use the parameters similar to the following to make the successful connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -key my_key.pem -cert my_cert.pem -pass file:my_passphrase
```

- **my_key.pem** is the filename of my private key
- **my_cert.pem** is the filename of the self-signed certificate forwarded to the service operator.
- **my_passphrase** contains the passphrase for the private key.

I am now trying to access the same service using gSOAP and its C bindings. I followed the documentation at http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html to create binding from the service WSDL and added a call to `soap_ssl_client_context()` to set up the SSL connection, but I'm running into a problem.

I presumed that I should use the path to **my_key.pem** as the `keyfile` parameter, but using gdb, I can see that it is the call to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` which is failing.
gSOAP passes the `keyfile` parameter as the `file` argument to this call.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that gSOAP expects the certificate and key to be in the **same file**.

From [SSL Certificates and Key Files](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.24) in the gSOAP documentation:

> The keyfiles (client.pem and server.pem) are created by concatenating the private key PEM with the certificate PEM.

You can achieve this by **concatenating** the two files together. This is simple using the Unix tool `cat`. At your shell prompt, and using the same file names as in the question:

```
$ cat my_cert.pem my_key.pem > my_certkey.pem
```

Where `my_certkey.pem` is the output file. Now, you can use the path to `my_certkey.pem` as the keyfile parameter in the call to `soap_ssl_client_context()`.

Tools like `openssl s_client` and `curl` will understand the concatenated key-cert file as argument to the `-cert` options and use both the key and cert from there.